# Need help to get the last page from scrollTop with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just learn about javascript and need A little bit help to get the last page element from jquery scrollTop.

So here my code :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("ul.pages li").each(function(i,e){
                    var offset = $(e).offset();
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= offset.top){
            $(".right_footer").text($(e).attr("data-id"));
        }   
    })
});
```

In html code

```
<ul class="pages">
   <li class="section" data-id="page_1"></li>
   <li class="section" data-id="page_2"></li>
   <li class="section" data-id="page_3"></li>
   <li class="section" data-id="page_4"></li>
</ul>
```

Well, when I scrolling the page I got all the value from `data-id` ( `page_1`,`page_2`,`page_3`,`NAN` ), but I can not get the last value from `data-id="page_4"`, javascript said `NAN`.

Can anybody help me??

Thanks All!

Comment: make a http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can see the whole page (including CSS)

Comment: @Deryck - You gave him the wrong link. It should bt [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: offset.top of what?  It's not attached to anything.  Would it be $(this).offset().top?

Comment: Thanks All, I try to create the file from jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: @kellycode, I just edit my question, please check...sorry :)

Comment: For what it's worth, here's my fiddle. I'm not seeing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/8vKqg/1/

Comment: Hi all, here check the my code http://jsfiddle.net/X5GxG/ thanks :)

Comment: @AustinMullins, please check my code, why in my case I can not get my last value http://jsfiddle.net/X5GxG/, thanks

Comment: @ilovebali You didn't make the li height big enough. http://jsfiddle.net/X5GxG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with your code, it's just that you weren't able to see the result on the last list item because it wasn't tall enough to scroll off the page. With the addition of real content, this problem will go away. In the meantime, you can simulate large blocks of content by specifying the height of your `li` elements in the page's CSS as demonstrated below:

```
ul.pages{
  float:left;
  width:1024px;
  height:auto;
}

li.page{
  width:1024px;
  height:700px; /* <-- Make this huge in the absence of content */
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just comment, It was your solution is work :)

Answer (score 0):

This jquery help to  force your browser to go to the top of your page:

```
$(".yourElementClass").click(function(){
 $(".yourDivName").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, ’slow’);
 });
```